# Create node and relationship given parent node

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am creating a word tree but when I execute this cypher query:

```
word = "MATCH {} MERGE {}-[:contains]->(w:WORD {{name:'{}'}}) RETURN w"
    .format(parent_node, parent_node, locality[i])
```

where `parent_node` has a type `Node`

It throws this error:

```
py2neo.cypher.error.statement.InvalidSyntax: Can't create `n8823` with properties or labels here. It already exists in this context
```

formatted query looks like this:

```
'MATCH (n8823:HEAD {name:"sanjay"}) MERGE (n8823:HEAD {name:"sanjay"})-[:contains]->(w:WORD {name:\'colony\'}) RETURN w'
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatted query is broken and won't work, but I also don't see how that could be what the formatted query actually looks like. When you do your string format you pass the same parameter (`parent_node`) twice so the final string should repeat whatever that parameter looks like. It doesn't, and instead has two different patterns for the match and merge clauses.

Your query should look something like

```
MATCH (n8823:Head {name: "sanjay"})
MERGE (n8823)-[:CONTAINS]->(w:Word {name: "colony"})
RETURN w
```

It's probably a bad idea to do string formatting on a `Node` object. Better to **either** use property values from your node object in a Cypher query to match the right node (and only the variable that you bind the matched node to in the merge clause) **or** use the methods of the node object to do the merge.

Comment: How do I get this value n8823?

Comment: It's the name of the variable to which you are binding your match. I used the same variable name that you had in your query, I don't know why you use that variable name. I assume it comes from `parent_node` when you use it in your format string.

Comment: How do you extract n8823 from a node object?

Answer (score 0):

Although the `MERGE` clause is able to bind identifiers (like `n8823`), Cypher unfortunately does not allow `MERGE` to *re-bind* an identifier that had already been bound -- even if it would not actually change the binding. (On the other hand, the `MATCH` clause *does* allow "rebinding" to the same binding.) Simply *re-using* a bound identifier is OK, though.

So, the workaround is to change your Cypher query to re-use the bound identifier. Also, the recommended way to dynamically specify query data without changing the overall structure of a query is to use "query parameters". For py2neo, code along these lines should work for you (note that the `parent_name` variable would contain a name string, like "sanjay"):

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()
cypher = graph.cypher
results = cypher.execute(
  "MATCH (foo:{name:{a}}) MERGE (foo)-[:contains]->(w:WORD {{name:'{b}'}}) RETURN w",
  a=parent_name, b=locality[i])
```

Comment: Actually, I can't do this. I have added this statement in a loop, hence takes the value as the loop iterates. So foo's label keeps on changing.

Comment: I tried this: MATCH {} CREATE UNIQUE {}-[:contains]-(w:WORD {{name:'{}'}}) RETURN w, I am facing the same issue.